# using dojo NumberTextBox.displayMessage

Tags: dojo

I am using NumberTextBox.displayMessage("errorMsg") to display error message,but it does not work.Here is my code:

```
numberInput.on("keyPress", function(event){
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        if (numberInput.get("value") <= 0) {
            numberInput.displayMessage('number must larger than 0!');
        }   
    }
});
```

I want to display message like when input some chars message will always show with red color!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't add your own key listeners to Dijit controls. Use the existing mechanisms for validation.

The NumberTextBox has function `isInRange` and you should overwrite it to get the result you want:

```
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(NumberTextBox){
    new NumberTextBox({
          name: "programmatic",
        isInRange: function(){
            var value = this.get('value')
            return value > 0
        },
        rangeMessage:'Number must be larger than 0'
    }, "number-box").startup();
});
```

See **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb6v1qkb/)**.